# Подавление CanExecute интерфейса ICommand UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

На странице, реализующей вход в систему, есть кнопка с привязанной командой. Команда реализует интерфейс ICommand, а метод CanExecute проверяет возможность вызова метода Execute, реализующего вход в систему. Например, проверка поля на корректность ввода:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is User user)
    {
        if (user.Email.Length == 0 || user.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            (new MessageDialog("Заполните все поля", "Ошибка входа")).ShowAsync();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Считывая данные из файла и записав их в поля, метод отрабатывает как надо. Но проблема заключается в том, что если данные из файла не прочитаны, и поля остаются пустыми, тут же появляется сообщение, требующее ввод этих самых пустых полей.

Каким образом можно подавить вызов метода CanExecute сразу же после начала работы приложения, а вызывать только в случае клика по кнопке?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68782/discussion-on-question-by----canexecute--icomma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CanExecute` сделан для того, чтобы не разрешить выполнение команды, а не для внедрения логики валидации.

Замените `user.Email.Length == 0` на `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email)` и то же самое с паролем, и перенесите валидацию и попап из `CanExecute` в логику команды. Тогда кнопка будет доступна если что-то введено (кроме пробелов), а проверка введенного будет только после нажатия. Также для валидации доступны атрибуты `[Required]` и атрибуты соответствия регулярке, имейлу и т.п.